# Wald test for pglm regression objects

Tags: r, logistic-regression, panel-data

I am trying to do a Wald test for a panel logit model returned by the pglm() function. Unfortunately, there is no standard Wald test method defined in the package for the maxLik object returned by the function.

I would be thankful for suggestions on how to perform a Wald test for a pglm maxLik object.

My formula is:

```
model1 <- pglm(DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + some_controls, index = c("person_id","year_id"), family = "binomial", model = "random", data = data_frame_name)
```

The pglm object attributes are:

```
class(model1)
[1] "maxLik" "maxim"  "list"

names(model1)
[1] "maximum"     "estimate"    "gradient"    "hessian"     "code"        "message"     "last.step"   "fixed"       "iterations" 
[10] "type"        "gradientObs" "control"     "call"        "args"        "model"  

names(summary(model1))
[1] "maximType"     "iterations"    "returnCode"    "returnMessage" "loglik"        "estimate"      "fixed"         "NActivePar"   
[9] "constraints"
```

Comment: What do you want to test?  Typically people are interested if your model is "better" than a baseline model.  If this is the case, estimate your baseline model also, and do likelihood ratio test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I may do that on top of the Wald test!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a straightforward way of doing Wald tests for every regression object that supports the "coef" and "vcov" methods using the "aod" package.

```
library(aod)
wald.test(b = coef(model1), Sigma = vcov(model1), Terms = 1:2)
```

The "Terms" attribute allows specifying what terms from the model should be jointly tested. I found the test [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm).

I also ran the test in Stata - it provides slightly different results, but they are still reasonably close to the values the aod test provides. However, if somebody knows alternative ways of calculating Wald tests in R or can explain why there might be a difference between the Stata and aod test values, please still let me know!